# Join multi unique key table but return just one row

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have import list as table below `import_order pk:import_date ,import_no, product_id`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
import_date | import_no | product_id | supplier_id | purchase_cost | qty |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-02  | M0001     | p00001     | s00001      | 2500          | 7   |
2018-01-02  | M0001     | p00002     | s00001      | 2700          | 4   |
2018-01-02  | M0001     | p00003     | s00001      | 3500          | 5   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to join supplier detail with table below

```
supplier_detail

-------------------------------------------------
 supplier_id | supplier_name   | tel            |
-------------------------------------------------
 s00001      | DevelopGlasses  | +11254421478   |
 s00002      | Operalise       | +11252232547   |
 s00003      | Azuing          | +11245454478   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to query to be result like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import_date | import_no| product_id | supplier_id| supplier_name| tel          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-02  | M0001    | p00001     | s00001     |DevelopGlasses|+11254421478  |
2018-01-02  | M0001    | p00002     | s00001     |DevelopGlasses|+11254421478  |
2018-01-02  | M0001    | p00003     | s00001     |DevelopGlasses|+11254421478  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*this is my sql*

```
SELECT i.*,s.* FROM import_order i INNER JOIN supplier_detail s ON i.s_id = s.s_id
```

result is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import_date | import_no| product_id | supplier_id| supplier_name| tel          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-02  | M0001    | p00001     | s00001     |DevelopGlasses|+11254421478  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `please help it urgent` ... please don't say this.  We already know you need help, or else you wouldn't have posted in the first place.

Comment: It is giving the right answer. Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9be791/3

Comment: Your query should already be working.

Comment: Please explain why you would want to match to rows when the supplier ids don't match.  This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi. Giving an example is good, but we can't cut & paste that & you didn't give it via cut & paste either. Eg your claimed output does not agree with your input. Eg What is right, s_id or supplier_id? Also you don't explain how output is a function of input, so it's not clear what your example is an example of & what should be the answer in other cases. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `on` condition as

```
SELECT i.import_date, i.import_no, i.product_id, 
       i.supplier_id, s.supplier_name, s.tel    
FROM import_order i 
INNER JOIN supplier_detail s 
      ON i.supplier_id = s.supplier_id; -- instead of i.s_id = s.s_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join, inner join select related records only

```
SELECT i.*,s.* FROM import_order i LEFT JOIN supplier_detail s ON i.s_id = s.s_id
```

Comment: Thank you but this command return result like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLINu.png

Comment: yep give the sql for the data set you mention if the data set is different this would be like you mention